# How do I select one class out of multiple, if they have a common keyword?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking to fetch an object's class. I currently have 9 elements that have the `class kit0 - kit8.` They also each have the class `kitContainer`. I want to fetch that `kit0 - kit8` classes just like `$(object).attr('class')` does. How should I do this? Is there a better way than using `.hasClass()`?

Comment: Why dont you change to a data attribute (eg `data-kit="0"`) - it'll make your life a lot easier.

Comment: hasClass? regExp? I personally would use a data attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use the anti-pattern of a numbered class, give your elements `data-*` attributes which are much easier to read in this way:

```js
$('.kitContainer').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('kit'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kitContainer" data-kit="0">0</div>
<div class="kitContainer" data-kit="1">1</div>
<div class="kitContainer" data-kit="2">2</div>
```

Comment: i guess i could add that in addition to my classes, but i do actually use the classes to add a specific image to the div.

Comment: I ended up using this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Its no problem @PolTimmer glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

If your `class` attributes are complicated, you can match and filter them, as below.

But if you can change your HTML, please do [use `data-` attributes, as suggested by Jamiec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132172/1850609).

```js
$(".kitContainer").each(function() {
  var thisKit = this.className.split(/\s+/).find(function(cls) {
    return /^kit\d/.test(cls);
  });
  console.log('kit for ' + this.innerText + ':', thisKit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kitContainer kit8">8</div>
<div class="kitContainer">no kit</div>
<div class="kitContainer kit1">1</div>
<div class="kitContainer kit2">2</div>
<div class="kitContainer kit3">3</div>
<div class="kitContainer kit4">4</div>
<div class="kitContainer kit5">5</div>
<div class="kitContainer kit6">6</div>
<div class="kitContainer kit7">7</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   $(".kitContainer").each(function(){
$(this).attr("class").replace("kitContainer","");//this line will give you class name. you can store it as you want
});
```